# can't understand why I am getting this result of HAVING COUNT

Tags: sql, group-by, count, union, having

Here is my sample DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `animals` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `condition` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `animal` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `animals` (`id`, `condition`, `animal`) VALUES
  ('1', 'fat', 'cat'),
  ('2', 'slim', 'cat'),
  ('3', 'fat', 'dog'),
  ('4', 'slim', 'dog'),
  ('5', 'normal', 'dog');
```

I am making the following request:

```
SELECT result.condition FROM
(
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'cat'
UNION
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'dog'
) as result
```

and get what I expect:

```
condition
---------
fat
slim
fat
slim
normal
```

Now I want to get only that values which have duplicates.
I modify my request by adding the last line:

```
SELECT result.condition FROM
(
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'cat'
UNION
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'dog'
) as result
HAVING COUNT(result.condition) > 1
```

but my actual result is:

```
condition
---------
fat
```

While I want to get:

```
condition
---------
fat
slim
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

P.S.
This part om my request can't be changed.

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'cat'
UNION
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'dog'
```

I am simplifying my actual request, but the main idea remains: I get a column of values as a result of UNION of 2 requests.

P.P.S. I am not looking for the most efficient request, I am looking for what will be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `union`. Just filter, aggregate and `having`:

```
select `condition`
from animals
where animal in ('cat', 'dog')
group by `condition`
having count(*) > 1
```

If you do want `union`, then you need a `group by` clause in the outer query to make your query a valid aggregation query:

```
SELECT `condition` 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'cat'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal = 'dog'
) as result
GROUP BY `condition`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Side note: `condition` is [a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, so not a good choice for a column name.

Comment: As I said I am simplifying my actual request, but the main idea remains: I get a column of values as a result of UNION of 2 requests. I fact these requests are far more complex.